# Significance of Vf terminal in Li-Ion Battery

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging

i was going through some propriety schematics that i can't post

the battery used in the schematic is a li-ion battery of 3.8V/2.1Ah/ from samsung, which gives out three pins `+` `-` `vf`

i have seen batteries in my previous experience trying give a thermistor output which conveys the temperature value of battery

but what exactly is `vf` here, i came across some one calling it a forward voltage of diode which is used inside the battery, the `vf` from battery was going to an ADC in my design

some useful link i have found is [here](http://9600n81.blogspot.in/2013/06/whats-inside-nokia-bl-5cx-battery.html) which speaks about internals of a `nokia bl5c`, as the design is of a smartphone itself i assume this battery would be similar to mine

in short i know this is been used for battery detection but i want a clear cut idea on how is this helping

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about this particular battery, but I have seen two uses for third battery pin:

- battery detection. For example, ISL9228 is a battery charger IC. Its datasheet http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/isl9/isl9228.pdf says:

  > VF (Pin 7)
  >
  > VF is an input pin for the battery ID resistor connection. This pin
  >   has an internal 1000kΩ pull-up resistor. Thus a typical 20kΩ ID
  >   resistor will pull this pin to logic low state, indicating a valid
  >   battery connection. If the battery is removed, the VF pin will be
  >   pulled to a logic high state by the internal resistor, the charger
  >   will be disabled as a result, regardless of the status of the EN pin.
  >   The maximum ID resistor is 100kΩ.
- Battery temperature monitoring. Smart Battery Specification http://sbs-forum.org/specs/sbdat110.pdf gives an example:

  > As a required safety feature, the charger must NOT
  >   charge a battery when it senses the resistance between the Safety
  >   Signal pin and ground to be in the range between 425 and 3150 ohms. A
  >   NiMH battery which may use a 103AT thermistor as the source of the
  >   Safety Signal would enter this range if it got too hot; or the Safety
  >   Signal of a Li-ion battery may which use discrete resistors could be
  >   set to this range in an emergency condition.

Comment: what `f` signifies ?, some one said me its forward voltage of a diode circuit present with battery that is why `Vf`

Comment: It is possible to measure temperature with a diode. It is possible that batteries used to have a diode inside for that purpose. Most modern ones do not -- even the page you reference mentioned resistor, not diode. If you have a battery on-hand, you can trivially check if it has resistor or diode with a multimeter.

Comment: There is a patent by Samsung on smart battery pack: http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2014/0055095.html . It involves using diode to sense temperature using a pin named 'Vf'. This may be the reason Samsung likes to call third battery page pin Vf.